# "The website encountered an unexpected error" when creating contrib and custom folders

Tags: theming

My Bootstrap Theme in Drupal is currently in the location *var/www/html/project/themes/bootstrap* on my laptop.
However, when I create a new directory- *contrib* (inside the themes directory) and move the *bootstrap* directory into it, I get the 'website encountered error' message. I launch the website via chrome using *.localhost/project*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the cache after you move thing around. Typically you would do this with Drush from your command line:

```
drush cr
```